# unable to open private key file for readin error

Tags: email, exim

when i run '**mail -vs "Test DKIM" test_acc@gmail.com < /dev/null**' i'm getting this error:

```
LOG: MAIN PANIC
  unable to open private key file for reading: /etc/exim/dkim.private.key #0
```

dkim.private.key file exist and owner is **root**

Full log:

```
WARNING: purging the environment.
 Suggested action: use keep_environment and add_environment.

delivering 1cEeEN-0000u6-8U
Connecting to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [64.233.167.26]:25 ... connected
  SMTP<< 220 mx.google.com ESMTP zw7si24925107wjb.31 - gsmtp
  SMTP>> EHLO mail.test.com
  SMTP<< 250-mx.google.com at your service, [193.70.43.73]
         250-SIZE 157286400
         250-8BITMIME
         250-STARTTLS
         250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
         250-PIPELINING
         250-CHUNKING
         250 SMTPUTF8
  SMTP>> STARTTLS
  SMTP<< 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
  SMTP>> EHLO mail.test.com
  SMTP<< 250-mx.google.com at your service, [193.70.43.73]
         250-SIZE 157286400
         250-8BITMIME
         250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
         250-PIPELINING
         250-CHUNKING
         250 SMTPUTF8
  SMTP>> MAIL FROM:<root@mail.test.com> SIZE=1538
  SMTP>> RCPT TO:<test_acc@gmail.com>
  SMTP>> DATA
  SMTP<< 250 2.1.0 OK zw7si24925107wjb.31 - gsmtp
  SMTP<< 250 2.1.5 OK zw7si24925107wjb.31 - gsmtp
  SMTP<< 354  Go ahead zw7si24925107wjb.31 - gsmtp
  SMTP>> writing message and terminating "."
LOG: MAIN PANIC
  unable to open private key file for reading: /etc/exim/dkim.private.key #0
  SMTP<< 250 2.0.0 OK 1481124843 zw7si24925107wjb.31 - gsmtp
  SMTP>> QUIT
LOG: MAIN
  => test_acc@gmail.com R=dnslookup T=remote_smtp H=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [64.233.167.26] X=TLSv1.2:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:128 C="250 2.0.0 OK 1481124843 zw7si24925107wjb.31 - gsmtp"
LOG: MAIN
  Completed
```

Answer (score 0):

DKIM shouldn't be running as root.

Give your DKIM user the right to read the key and restart the DKIM service.